# I am not getting the right result, not sure what I am missing (improper logic, missing steps?)

Tags: java

I am trying to get this problem to work right, what it does it ask for some scores to be entered and then it is supposed to show the name of the person with the highest score. I am getting the last score entered as the highest score, the problem with that is the last score entered is not going to necessarily be the highest one entered. Any ideas on how I can fix this would be appreciated. This is homework and just so nobody says "use a list or array" we have not covered that in class and thus are not supposed to use it for this problem.

```
       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
            // variables
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int count = 0;
            int numStudents;
            double grade = 0, highestGrade = 0;
            String name = "", highName = "";

            String numGrades =
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                    ("How many student grades are you entering: ");
            numStudents = Integer.parseInt(numGrades);

            //for(int count = 0; count < numStudents; count++)
            while(count < numStudents)
            {
            // prompt for the user to enter grades
            String inputName =
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a student name: ");
            name = inputName;
            //name = input.next(inputName);

            String inputGrade = 
                   JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is that students grade: ");
            grade = Double.parseDouble(inputGrade);
            //grade = input.nextDouble();

            count++; 
            //if(grade < highestGrade)
            if(highestGrade > grade)
            {
                name = highName;
                grade = highestGrade;
            }
            else 
            {
                continue;
            }        
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
                    (null, "The student with the highest score is " + name + 
                    " with a grade of " + grade);           
        }
```

Comment: If this is homework, I'd imagine your professor is interested in an OO approach since you are using Java. Why not make a Student class with their name and grade , and then store them in a List. From there, you could traverse the list and see which student is highest.

Comment: Well, looking very quickly, you have the `highestGrade` variable initialized with 0 and you are comparing it with the forthcoming grades. You need to actualize the `highestGrade` variable as you keep finding higher grades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 if(highestGrade > grade)
            {
                name = highName;
                grade = highestGrade;
            }
```

Since you want to find the highest grade and name, the above should be in reverse.

```
 if(grade > highestGrade )
            {
                highName = name;
                highestGrade = grade;
            }
```

Also, print the *found* values:

```
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
                 (null, "The student with the highest score is " + highName +  
                  " with a grade of " + highestGrade);
```

Comment: And change to JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
                    (null, "The student with the highest score is " + name + 
                    " with a grade of " + highestGrade);

Comment: +1. And also when printing to the console, OP should print _highName_ and _highestGrade_

Comment: @Juvanis & Todd, Thanks. I didn't notice that :) I edited it.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was something simple like that. Also, I would have preferred to use a list for this as it would have made it so much easier to get the highest score, or whatever one I wanted, but the instructor wanted it done without a list or array because he has not "taught" us that yet. Again, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

This is backwards:

```
if(highestGrade > grade)
```

should be

```
if(highestGrade < grade)
```

or more understandably:

```
if(grade > highestGrade)
```

EDIT:  This is also backwards...

```
name = highName;
grade = highestGrade;
```